# Getting SQLState: 08001 with JDBC and postgresql although server was already connected

Tags: java, database, networking, jdbc, debian

The config on which the error occurs is:

```
debian 6,
tomee+ 1.5.2,
postgres 9.2,
hibernate 4.1.2,
```

I try to import a bunch of data which works very well till a random point where i get an `SQLState: 08001` and the server throws an `java.net.NoRouteToHostException`. Before that the server was connected and already dumped some data to the database. I already tried to give more resources to the server but doesn't help. It works on several other osx machines. 
Would be great if someone maybe know a resolution.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Is the Pg machine on the same host as the client? I'm guessing transient network connection issues.

Comment: Hi, yes it is. And i had already a connection...

Comment: Sure, but you can "already have a connection" and still get a no route to host when packets being sent on that connection can not be delivered. It's not just at connection establishment time. What address are you connecting to? Can you show the *full* exception stack trace and the JDBC URL?

Comment: The connection is established over localhost:5432. I posted the stacktrace on http://pastebin.com/7GYV8FPz because i don't know how to  add it here :) Is there a possibility?

Comment: No route to host ... on local loopback. Bizarre. Firewall config issue perhaps? Anything shown by `iptables -L -n` or `iptables -t nat -L -n` ? Really shouldn't happen. Alternately, any chance `localhost` resolves to an address other than `127.0.0.1`? Try using `127.0.0.1:5432` instead.

Comment: Will try this later. That real bizarre thing is that i get this error on several linux machines and not on OSX.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work with 127.0.0.1. If i turn on extended logging on postgres the import is slowed down and it runs without exception.

Comment: Your next step is to pull out Wireshark, trace the communication between server and client, and see if you can spot anything weird going on that correlates to the errors.